# Using MVC pattern for JS app with multiple models

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, design-patterns

I'm trying to comprehend usage of MVC pattern for JS application in case of working with multiple models. For example, I have a page with user info, his orders and executors of order. I need to show some user info and make orders and executors editing. So I have 3 models and need controller and view for each. Besides orders and executors are in lists. All lists for consecutive use in models must be loaded from server. What approaches should I use to manage multiple MVC entities in one page? Maybe another design patterns, etc.

**UPDATE** 
To clarify 
But, if I need to make a separate page where I work only with orders or only with executors. It is logical that these should be separate entities so that they can be used in various tasks. I thought that, in this case, perhaps, it is necessary to assemble one "large" model from the "small" models to solve a specific problem, or to make some kind of interface for interaction between models.
What am I talking about? For example, when I load orders from the server, I also load some information about the executor, i.e. in a SQL database, this is done by some JOIN of two tables. Which of the models to make a request for loading? Obviously orders. How, then, initialize the executor model data? Okay, I'm doing one big model where are all data I need about all of the entities in my application.
Ok, the page (modal, whatever) for executor's editing. There is no need for order data or customer (user) data. For this I use the same model, where some of the data and functions associated with them will not be used. Something is not sticking with me :)

Answer (score 0):

Just a correction, MVC is an [architectural pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Architectural_pattern) and not a design pattern. However the 2 differ by a thin line so its very easy to mistakely interchange both during discussions.

Irrespective, MVC should be a good approach to structure your code:

```
- authentication [Feature1]
    - pages
       - signin_page.htm
       - authentication.css
       - signup_page.htm
    - models
       - user_info.js
       - signin_info.js
    - auth_controller.js
 - orders [Feature2]
    - pages
    - models
       - order_info.js
       - payment_info.js
    - order_controller.js
 - Feature3
 - Feature4
 - shared [all common things]
    - services
       - http_service.js
    - models
       - error_info.js
```

Basically you can create a folder for each feature or functionality and then inside that on a need basis create folders namely pages/views and models and then 1 or more controllers for each feature and a single generic service to do http calls which should take parameters and url as input and should handle all the error handling.